# Why I am getting this error in a method: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new with classes in Python 3. What I am trying to do is rewrite a function in a class, but when I run it. I got this error:

> ```
> <ipython-input-67-42b4fc5729b3> in savage(self)
>      11         list1 = list()
>      12         while i < len(self.Acciones):
> ---> 13             self.test3 = [self.MatPagos - self.test2  for self.MatPagos, self.test2  in zip(self.test2,self.MatPagos[0])]
>      14             list1.append(self.test3)
>      15             i += 1
>
> TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
> ```

This is the function and it runs perfectly:

```
def Savage(Acciones,MatPagos):
    test = [list(x) for x in zip(*MatPagos)]
    test2 = [max(k) for k in test]

    i = 0
    list1 = list()
    while i < len(Acciones):
        test3 = [MatPagos - test2 for MatPagos, test2 in zip(test2,MatPagos[i])]
        list1.append(test3)
        i += 1

    MatPagos = list1
```

and this gave me this result:

`[[0, 0, 3200, 8600], [1200, 1200, 0, 3200], [2400, 2400, 1200, 0]]`

This is how I rewrite it for the class:

```
class savage_c(wald):
    def savage(self):
        super().getMatPagos()
        self.test = [list(x) for x in zip(*self.MatPagos)]
        self.test2 = [max(k) for k in self.test]

        i = 0
        list1 = list()
        while i < len(self.Acciones):
            self.test3 = [self.MatPagos - self.test2 for self.MatPagos, self.test2 in zip(self.test2,self.MatPagos[i])]
            list1.append(self.test3)
            i += 1

        self.MatPagos = self.list1
        print(self.MatPagos)
```

These are the variable content:

```
print(self.MatPagos)
>>> [[200, 3200, 1800, -1800], [-1000, 2000, 5000, 3600], [-2200, 800, 3800, 6800]]
print(self.test)
>>> [[200, -1000, -2200], [3200, 2000, 800], [1800, 5000, 3800], [-1800, 3600, 6800]]
print(self.test2)
>>> [200, 3200, 5000, 6800]
```

What am I missing?

Comment: is `self.MatPagos` ever an integer?

Comment: @chrisz It is a list of list

Comment: Due to your error, I think that may not be true always.

Comment: You are assigning to `self.MatPagos` in your list comprehension, so it is changing to something you don't expect.  `[... for self.MatPagos, self.test2 in ...]`.  In fact, using `self` in that context is incredibly abnormal and almost certainly an error.

Comment: why is it anormal? @0x5453

Comment: @chrisz I added the content of these variables in my question.

Comment: @virtualdvid, yes but see @0x5453's comment.  You are assigning other values to `self.MatPagos` in your list comprehension.

Comment: @virtualdvid because you are assigning to an instance variable while you iterate, what do you expect `for self.x, y in zip(it1, it2)` to *do*? Because each time it assignes *somethig* to `self.x`, which works exactly as if you did `self.x = something`

Comment: What I am expecting to get is the rest between the array test2 and MatPagos column by column. `[[200 - 200], [200-(-1000)], [200-(-2200)]]`. It works perfectly in the function giving me this result `[[0, 0, 3200, 8600], [1200, 1200, 0, 3200], [2400, 2400, 1200, 0]]` but I am so lost when it is in a class. :/ @juanpa.arrivillaga

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@0x5453 you where right but I couldn't visualize it.

I got this [answer](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/137545/porqu%C3%A9-obtengo-este-error-en-un-m%C3%A9todo-int-object-is-not-subscriptable/137550#137550) for @FJSevilla in the Stack Spanish version:

You shouldn't use the attribute as an internal variable in a list comprehension. When you do:

```
self.test3 = [self.MatPagos - self.test2 for self.MatPagos, self.test2 in zip(self.test2, self.MatPagos[i])]
```

You overwrite the values of the attributes `self.MatPagos` and `self.test2`, in a way that in the second iteration both are integers and not the initial lists. Do something like:

```
self.test3 = [matP - test2 for matP, test2 in zip(self.test2, self.MatPagos[i])]
```

I recommend you to use a `for` instead a while when you can. it is more "pythonic" and more efficient. If you iterate over all rows of `self.MatPagos`, it will be:

```
def savage(self):
    self.test = [list(x) for x in zip(*self.MatPagos)]
    self.test2 = [max(k) for k in self.test]

    self.MatPagos  = [[matP - test2 for matP, test2 in zip(self.test2, mprow)] for mprow in self.MatPagos]
```